# Show that $f\cdot g\equiv 0$ on D implies either $f\equiv 0$ or $g\equiv 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> Let $D$ be a domain and $f,g:D\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic functions. Show that $f\cdot g\equiv 0$ on $D$ implies either $f\equiv 0$ or $g\equiv 0$.

I have a vague idea for a proof:
Let's assume $g\neq 0$ for some $z\in D$, i.e. $z_0$. It follows that $f(z_0)=0$. Now if $z_0$ is a limit point, the identity theorem implies that $f\equiv 0$ on $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $D$. Then for every point $z$ of $K$, either $f(z) = 0$ or $g(z) = 0$. So at least one of $f$ or $g$ has infinitely many roots in $K$. Since $K$ is compact, these infinitely many roots will have a limit point in $K$, so that $f$ or $g$ must be identically $0$.

Comment: So my proof would be correct if I restrict it to a compact subset? I guess there must be some theorem stating that on a compact set there will be a limit point? Which is it though?

Comment: The theorem I'm using is that any infinite subset of a compact set has a limit point. This theorem is not true for open sets: consider $1-\frac{1}{n}$ in the open unit disk.

Comment: I only know limit points in the context of sequences. It seems the identity theorem takes another definition of limit points. Could you explain that as well?

Comment: I don't think it takes another version. So a limit point of a set $E$ is a point $z$ (that might be in $E$ or not) so that every nbhd of $z$ intersects $E\setminus\{z\}$. A limit point of a sequence $(z_1,z_2,\dots)$ is the same as a limit point of the set $\{z_1,z_2,\dots\}$. So the theorem I mentioned says that, in particular, any sequence in a compact set has a limit point in that compact set.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: It is not necessary that $K$ has to be compact..!

Comment: Nobody said it was necessary.... but it is sufficient

Answer (score 3):

You would need to conclude that with $g(z_0)\ne 0$ then by continuity also $g(z)\ne 0$ for all $z\in B(z_0,r)$ for some small $r>0$. Then $f(z)=0$ on an open set, but all roots of non-zero holomorphic functions are isolated.

Comment: What if $B(z_0, r) \cap D = \{z_0\}$?

I think we need to assume that $D$ has a nonempty interior. Otherwise we can take $D=\{0,\frac{π}{2}\}$ and $f=\sin,g=\cos$.

Comment: A domain $D$ in complex analysis is always a simply connected open set.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't familiar with this convention.

Answer (score 2):

As $f\cdot g\equiv0$, therefore $D = Z_f \cup Z_g$ where $Z_f, Z_g$ are zero sets of $f$ and $g$ respectively.

Suppose $f \not \equiv 0$ and $g \not \equiv 0$. Then $Z_f$ and $Z_g$ are isolated sets. It follows that $D$ is an isolated set. But [we know](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535302) that a connected set with at least two points is not isolated.